# NextJS after build web appearance messed up

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi i have a problem after build the nextjs and start in local the appearance of the website become messed up

Is there anyone know this issue?

before build
[image: before build]
after build
[image: after build]

Comment: Does that code pushed to an online Version Control Tool? if so, and it's publicly available, please share the link, elsewise, please share the `next.config.js` file.

Comment: Also, this can be happening because a mix of named classes, maybe you can naming your CSS Classes differently. [BEM Naming](http://getbem.com/naming/)

Comment: Its still not live yet and its not public, inside next.config.js has withCSS() to enable me import css file. Im using material ui css which create a style internally inside each component and it will compile the name of the className into unique name for each component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using material ui there is a next.js version that cause this problem, use the latest version of Next.js

Comment: Does version next js 8.1 is okay? Or do i need to upgrade latest version? Evgeni fotia

Comment: @JassonHarsojo I just remembered now you absolutely need the the 9 version